# How to Upgrade cakephp 2.3.5 to 2.9.0 version

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I am using cakephp framework 2.3.5 version for my application And now i want to upgrade my cakephp version to 2.9.0.

Can you please suggest me the process how can i upgrade to 2.9.0 version?

Comment: Have you checked migration what are changes in 2.9 version???

Comment: Thanks for the reply mehul, first i am trying to upgrade to 2.8.0 & checked the migration guide http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-8-migration-guide.html. But i am not getting how to upgrade?

Comment: Kindly check this Result https://stackoverflow.com/a/58349194/5968928

Answer (score 1):

install cakephp version 2.8 in your local system, if you want to upgrade whole project then copy your controller,model and view from cakephp 2.3.5 project to your new project and checked that module there will be no major changes if you got any error then let me know.. I have upgraded from version 1.3 to 2.6..
and also read migration guide you will get better idea about new changes.