# Cakephp migration from 2.7 to 2.8 in cpanel

Tags: cakephp, migration, cakephp-2.7, cakephp-2.8

My website is developed in cakephp 2.7 which uses php.4.4 many years ago.All working fine at that time.

But right now it's not working in capnel. I have checked the issue and error logs. PDO class is not working and meanwhile database query execution is not working.

So i have upgraded my php version to PHP 7.0. Another issues are coming like problem in error handler of cakephp. I searched for this issue and i concluded that cakephp 2.7 is not compatible with PHP 7.0.

So i have to do migration from cakephp 2.7 to cakephp 2.8.

I have searched for the migration but no any link shows clear changes of code from 2.7 to 2.8.

I need proper documentation for the migration.

please anyone suggest some links for migration.

Comment: If you're upgrading, then do yourself a favour and upgrade to the latest 2.10.x release, there's not really a point in going to only 2.8.x, you'd just miss out on bug/compatibility fixes and features. That being said, the migration guides can be found in the docs: **https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices.html**. And if you want to see the actual code changes, use a local diff program, or make a comparison over at GitHub: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/compare/2.7.0...cakephp:2.10.17** (you'd have to narrow the tags as GitHub only shows the last 250 commits).

Comment: ok thanks for the link. Let me try in local first.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these simple steps to upgrade cakephp 2.x.x to any latest version of cakephp 2.x.x.

Till today [cakephp 2.10.19](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/tag/2.10.19) is latest one , so I will guide accordingly

1. First of all create backup or your data(eg:Maan.com) and database.
2. Make subdomain(eg: CakephpNewVersion.Maan.Com)
3. clone latest version of cakephp from git to your new subdomin.
4. Extract every thing to subdomin.
5. Copy/Owe right  these folders from orignal domain to subdomain "Config, Model,  View, Controllers, Webroot".

6: Create new database for subdomin and import db back that we took in step 1.

7: Modify subdomain(eg: CakephpNewVersion.Maan.Com)/app/config/database.php according to new database settings.

8: You are good to go , Refresh subdomin and compare everything with main Domain.
 9: If everything is as expected then Just vote up this answer and repeat this process to main domin/or just clone directory.